# Finding a tangent plane to the surface $g(x,y,z)=0$

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, partial-derivative

> Let $f(u,v)$ be a function with $f(-1,3)=0,\;f_{u}(-1,3)=2,\;f_{v}(-1,3)=-3$. Let $g(x,y,z)=f(xyz, x^2+y^2+z^2)$. Find an equation of the tangent plane to the surface $g(x,y,z)=0$ at the point $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,1).$

Clearly,

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x-1)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(y+1)-(z-1)=0\;...(*)$$

is the tangent plane to the surface $g(x,y,z)=0$ at the point $(1,-1,1)$

We have to find the partial derivatives:

$$u=xyz,\;v=x^2+y^2+z^2$$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

In the end we finally get:

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\bigg\vert_{(-1,3)}=-8$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\bigg\vert_{(-1,3)}=8$$

Using the values and (*) we get:

$$8x-8y+z=17$$

as a tangent plane to the surface to the surface $g(x,y,z)=0$ at the point $(1,-1,1)$

Is it true? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent plane writes
$$
g_x(x_0,y_0,z_0) (x-x_0)+
g_y(x_0,y_0,z_0) (y-y_0)+
g_z(x_0,y_0,z_0) (z-z_0)
$$

It is convenient to introduce the variables
$u=xyz,v=x^2+y^2+z^2$
so that
$g(x,y,z)=f(u,v)$ and
$g(x_0,y_0,z_0)=f(u_0,v_0)$.

It follows
$$
du = yz dx + xz dy + xy dz,
dv = 2x dx + 2y dy + 2z dz,
$$

From
\begin{eqnarray*}
df
&=&\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv \\
&=&
\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} yz+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} 2x
\right) dx +
\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} xz+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} 2y
\right) dy +
\left(
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} xy+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} 2z
\right) dz
\end{eqnarray*}
we deduce
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)&=&
f_u(u_0,v_0) y_0z_0+
f_v(u_0,v_0) 2x_0 \\
g_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)&=&
f_u(u_0,v_0) x_0z_0+
f_v(u_0,v_0) 2y_0 \\
g_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)&=&
f_u(u_0,v_0) x_0y_0+
f_v(u_0,v_0) 2z_0 
\end{eqnarray*}
From here, you can easily conclude.